# Chrome hyperlink urls are shown in brackets after the text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, css

I have an MVC4 site that displays fine in IE8, however in Chrome all the hyperlinks are displayed, Text then url in brackets like this:-

- Text (/Controller/Edit/37)

It looks CSS related but I am not sure how to find what is causing it.

Comment: Probably going to need to see the code, or a link to the site to answer this.